# How to retain the values of a label after invoking a function

Tags: javascript, html, validation, dom

I am just wondering why the label's text which i am setting below doesn't persists. If the user enters valid username & password say(xxx  & yyy) then the label should set with Welcome xxx, else set with "Login Failed". Here i see the label is set with right text, but in a fraction of second the page refreshes and all fields are set empty and the label text is erased. How to overcome this? I am trying in Firefox.

Following is my html code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
User Name: <input type="text" id="uname"/><br/><br/>
Password :  <input type="text" id="pwd"/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Login"onclick="validateLogin()"/><br/>
<label id="label1" /><br/>
<label id="label2" /><br/>
</form>
<script>
function validateLogin()
{
    var v1=document.getElementById("uname").value;
    var v2=document.getElementById("pwd").value;
    if(v1=="xxx" && v2=="yyy")
    {
        document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML="Welcome :"+v1;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Invalid login");
        document.getElementById("label2").innerHTML="Login Failed!!!";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess this is just for practice. Login validation client side is not the way to go..

Comment: Yes this is for practice purpose only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change markup like this

```
<input type="submit" value="Login"onclick="return validateLogin()"/> <!-- added return -->
```

**Javascript**

```
if (v1 == "xxx" && v2 == "yyy") {
    document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = "Welcome :" + v1;
    return false; /* return */
} else {
    alert("Invalid login");
    document.getElementById("label2").innerHTML = "Login Failed!!!";
    return false; /* return */
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xvgvLm1b/1/)

**Note:**  This will work as expected but those values need to post on server side while condition is `true` so in `if` block write your code to post data on server rather than printing it to the label and don't forget to remove `return false` from if after writing the code

Comment: It worked. Can you please tell me the importance of returning false here? This is just for practicing purpose, so setting values with Label.

Comment: @Uday When you call a function with return value you should initialize/get to some variable and `return false` will not send your request to server. As you're using [submit button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-button) to post data!

Comment: to reiterate, if i omit the return value, will it mean it is posting back to server? and coming to initial state? So the reason we are returning false, making sure not to post to server here. I am right or moving in different direction?